# Azure App Services Add array of strings in configuration

Tags: json, asp.net-core, appsettings, azure-appservice

Net core application and deploying the application in Azure App Services. In my application, I have an app settings.json file with below content

```
"Roles": {
    "Roles": [
        "Admins",
        "Users"
    ]
}
```

I have the below configuration in my ARM template.

Parameters.json

```
"Roles": {
    "value": [
        "Admins",
        "Users"
    ]
}
```

I am trying to add values in app settings as below

```
{
    "name": "Roles__Roles",
    "value": "[parameters('Roles')]" 
}
```

This is giving me an exception

> 2021-01-19T10:25:17.0538350Z ##[error]Details:
> 2021-01-19T10:25:17.0539754Z ##[error]undefined: HTTP request body must not be empty.

Can someone help me to fix this?

Answer (score 1):

As far as I understand, the app settings values provided for the App Service need to be of type string. However, your parameter "Roles" is of type array. Thus, a conversion to string is required. Try this:

```json
{
    "name": "Roles__Roles",
    "value": "[string(parameters('Roles'))]"
}
```

The same applies to parameters of type object.

Unfortunately, the error message is not at all helpful in clarifying this.

References:

- Microsoft Docs: [Template functions - string - Azure Resource Manager](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/templates/template-functions-string?tabs=json#string)
- Related question: [Error passing an array type as a parameter to an appsetting for an AppService Slot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58472169/error-passing-an-array-type-as-a-parameter-to-an-appsetting-for-an-appservice-sl)